# How to delete sliced sprites in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, game-engine, game-development

When I slicing a sprite in Unity.

I mistakenly **sliced a piece** that i don't want

Here the **Menu Buttons_0**

[image]

Now, I want to delete that garbage

Is there any way I can delete the **Menu Buttons_0**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**1**.Select the original image from the project tab.

**2**.While the image is selected, on Inspector tab, click Sprite Editor to open it.

**3**.Select the sprite to delete (Menu Buttons_0)

**4**.Hold the <kbd>Command</kbd> button key then press the <kbd>delete</kbd> key. On Windows, this should be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>. On some keyboards, it is the  <kbd>Function</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>.

This step depends on the type of keyboard you are using. If using Windows keyboard, pressing the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key is enough to handle this.

If using Apple keyboard either from bootcamp or some other ways, you will have to use one of the key combinations above.

**5**.Click Apply.

That's it.

Comment: thanks,I am windows 10. And it is **not Ctrl+Del key**. for my case just pressing **Delete** key is working. I also have a **Del** key but that's not working.

Comment: Only pressing **Delete** key is working fine on **Windows 10**

Comment: Yes, it depends on the keyboard type and the OS too. I've even had to use the function key + del to get it work on some keyboards(Apple keyboards). Added that to the answer

Answer (score 0):

For those using boot camp, it's `fn + shift + delete`.